# PHP check if there are no more results without using rowCount function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Normally to check count for the number of records being fetched from the database we use `rowCount` function while using PDO with PHP. However, I am stuck in a case where I want to have the same result to use in an `if...else` statement but I cannot use it and I will explain below with code example why.

Normal case:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$stmt-> execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count > 0){    
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        // Perform a task....
    }
}
```

Or, we also use `SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table` and then use fetch for the count element.

However, the problem in my case is I can't use these methods because they will return count value of the root query that was executed. And here I have an `if` condition which when satisfied loads the result and I want to count the total number of records satisfying that condition.

For example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$stmt-> execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    // Suppose I have a variable $distance which I calculated and based on that the result should appear
    if($distance < 100){
        // Display the records which satisfied this condition
        // Once the records are fetched, NOW I WANT TO COUNT THEM under "this" condition. 
        // This count will be based on the condition above which will be different from the root count using `rowCount`

        if($count == 0){
            // Perform a task here
        }
    }
}
```

How to count the number of records that satisfies under the condition `if($distance < 100)`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use that condition in query. `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE distance < $distance"`

Comment: _“How to count the number of records that satisfies under the condition if($distance < 100)?”_ - by doing `$countOfRecordsThatSatisfiedMyCondition++;` in that place …?

Comment: Best bet is to try and find a way to do the calculation in SQL. If it's too complicated, use what CBroe suggested.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie No I can't because distance is calculated from the result obtained from this query.

Comment: @CBroe sarcastic way to help.. thanks ;)

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap  try using `Joins` or using `routines` under `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie  No that won't work in this case. You didn't understood my question well. However, the answer below does the job which is same as suggested by Cbroe above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    if($distance < 100){
        $count++;
        // display records 
    }
}  

if($count == 0){
     // Perform a task here
}
```

You can just count the records with your while loop as shown above. I am assuming you have done `bind_result` of `$display`. Outside of the loop, if you find `count = 0`, then perform your desired task.

Comment: Can't use the 2nd one because there are two SQL queries to be specific. And distance is calculated using the data from 1st and 2nd both queries. Hence, distance is calculated inside the while loop (using data of each record from this one and subtracting from data of 1st record). Hence, the 1st solution seems appropriate.

Comment: However, are you sure I can use `if($count == 0)` condition outside while loop and it won't be an error (either visible or invisible) ?

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap I updated my answer to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap count condition outside of while loop won't be an issue. BTW, what task are you performing when count equals 0?

Comment: needed to add a class to hide and show elements based upon the records count. Say for example if records equals 0 then show the refresh button to refresh the page to check and load more records if exists.

Comment: And I got the logic now. You missed one thing here. Declaring `$count = 0` outside the while loop. So since the count value is outside the while loop it gets incremented by 1 each time the loop runs. The count variable being outside the while loop will definitely make it no issue using its updated value outside of the loop. I will update in your answer. Never mind :) Thanks :D

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap I just showed the demo, but never mind, I approved your edit :)